# React Native Expo - Node.js version 13.14.0 is no longer supported

Tags: javascript, react-native, ubuntu, server

ERROR: Node.js v13.14.0 is no longer supported.

expo-cli supports following Node.js versions:
* >=10.13.0 <11.0.0 (Maintenance LTS)
* >=12.13.0 <13.0.0 (Active LTS)
* >=14.0.0  <15.0.0 (Current Release)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

me too, you can turn down the level to NodeJS 12, it may works

Comment: https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-nodejs-on-ubuntu-debian-linux-mint/